# Unique column of a sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

What is a good way of identifying the unique columns of a sparse matrix represented in csc_matrix format and the times each column is repeated?

I have no information a priori about the elements of the matrix. It is the result of a sampling with replacement of the columns of another matrix, so I can have duplicated columns both due to the fact that a column is sampled many times either there are duplicated columns in the original matrix. Therefore I cannot apply `numpy.unique` to the indices of the sampled columns and I think it is not a good choice to convert the entire matrix to a dense format and then apply `numpy.unique` to it.

Comment: There's no one way to do this, so we can't, without experimentation, say which is most efficient.  Apply `np.unique` to the dense version is a good start.  Or depending on size and range of values, column sums might do the job, or at least identify possible candidates for duplication.  I'd also consider looking at the attributes of the `M.T.tolil()` matrix.  Duplicates will have matching `data` and `rows` lists.

Comment: Before anyone can give a useful answer you need to provide some samples, possibly a small toy one that can be used to test ideas, and a more realistic one to test efficiency.  It's easy to generate a random matrix in which every column is unique, except for the ones that are all 0s.

Comment: I have improved my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and group by the number of nonzeros in each column. Each group then sort by indices and values and split into blocks of no-change:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def sparse_unique_columns(M):
    M = M.tocsc()
    m, n = M.shape
    if not M.has_sorted_indices:
        M.sort_indices()
    if not M.has_canonical_format:
        M.sum_duplicates()
    sizes = np.diff(M.indptr)
    idx = np.argsort(sizes)
    Ms = M@sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones((n,)), idx, np.arange(n+1)), (n, n))
    ssizes = np.diff(Ms.indptr)
    ssizes[1:] -= ssizes[:-1]
    grpidx, = np.where(ssizes)
    grpidx = np.concatenate([grpidx, [n]])
    if ssizes[0] == 0:
        counts = [np.array([0, grpidx[0]])]
    else:
        counts = [np.zeros((1,), int)]
    ssizes = ssizes[grpidx[:-1]].cumsum()
    for i, ss in enumerate(ssizes):
        gil, gir = grpidx[i:i+2]
        pl, pr = Ms.indptr[[gil, gir]]
        dv = Ms.data[pl:pr].view(f'V{ss*Ms.data.dtype.itemsize}')
        iv = Ms.indices[pl:pr].view(f'V{ss*Ms.indices.dtype.itemsize}')
        idxi = np.lexsort((dv, iv))
        dv = dv[idxi]
        iv = iv[idxi]
        chng, = np.where(np.concatenate(
            [[True], (dv[1:] != dv[:-1]) | (iv[1:] != iv[:-1]), [True]]))
        counts.append(np.diff(chng))
        idx[gil:gir] = idx[gil:gir][idxi]
    counts = np.concatenate(counts)
    nu = counts.size - 1
    uniques = M@sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones((nu,)), idx[counts[:-1].cumsum()],
                                   np.arange(nu + 1)), (n, nu))
    return uniques, idx, counts[1:]


a = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (1000, 200))
a[a>1] = 0
a = sparse.csc_matrix(a)
b = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(1000), np.random.randint(0, 200, (1000,)), np.arange(1001)))
c = a@b

unq, idx, cnt = sparse_unique_columns(c)
unqd, idxd, cntd = np.unique(c.A, axis=1, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
from timeit import timeit

print('sparse:', timeit(lambda: sparse_unique_columns(c), number=1000), 'ms')
print('dense: ', timeit(lambda: np.unique(c.A, axis=1, return_counts=True), number=100)*10, 'ms')
```

Sample output:

```
sparse: 2.735588440205902 ms
dense:  49.32689592242241 ms
```

Comment: Can you please tell what's the meaning of `Ms = M@sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones((n,)), idx, np.arange(n+1)), (n, n))` and `view(f'V{ss*Ms.data.dtype.itemsize}')` ?

Comment: @momomi The first sorts the columns of `M` (by number of non-zeros) by multiplying with the appropriate (sparse) permutation matrix. The second combines chunks of `ss` elements (= columns) into single elements of `void` dtype. This accelerates sorting these columns.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, if I compile your code I get two errors: one about the syntax of 'view(f'V{ss*Ms.data.dtype.itemsize}')' and the second about a out of bounds in 'idx[gil:gir] = idx[gil:gir][idxi]' . Actually I have difficulty understanding what this last line means and how you can get the row indices of duplicated columns when comparing each M.data and M.indices element of each block.

Comment: @momomi What do you mean, compile? --- re the syntax error: Are you on an old python version? f-strings are a relatively new feature. How did you resolve this? Other error you are seeing may well be a follow-up. --- The line you find difficult sorts the current block of columns with given number of nonzeros.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 2.7 and I resolved by `V{s}.format(s=ss*Ms.data.dtype.itemsize)` but now raised another error : _idxi = np.lexsort((dv, iv)) ValueError: all keys need to be the same shape_ . Sorry but even if I omit `.view()`  I have an error in `idx[gil:gir][idxi]`: here you are extracting the indices of the ss columns of Ms accorting to idxi, which refers to the sorting of Ms.data[gil,gir], why?

Comment: @momomi Odd. So what are the shapes of `Ms.data[pl:pr]` and `Ms.indices[pl:pr]` and tof the associated void views when the error occurs? --- The sole purpose of the sorting is to have duplicates sitting next to each other for easy identification. Applying the sort order to idx is just book keeping because we later need to extract the uniques which is easier when idx is sorted. It may be possible to optimize that out, but I'm too tired right now to seriously look into it.

Comment: The error occurs at step 0 of the for cycle, where ss=1 in my case. --- Ok, but given a block, idxi keeps track of the order of the row indices of the elements of the block while idx of the columns of the sorted original  matrix, is this right?

Comment: This is not working e.g. for `a = np.array([[0, 3, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 2, 1]])`, `a = sparse.csr_matrix(a)`. It also doesn't work with non-square matrices?

Comment: @AndyK input must be cs**c** not cs**r**

Comment: @AndyK on top of that there was a bug in how all-zero columns are handled. Both should be fixed now. See updated post.